# Why doesnt "i" get incremented in the following code

Tags: python

I am new to coding and just stumbled upon these lines of code in "python"

```
a = [1,2,3,4,"hello"]

for i in a:
   try:
       print(i)
       i + 1
       print (("i is :  %d") %(i))
   except:
       print("nope " + i  + " is a string")
```

The output is:

```
1
i is :  1
2
i is :  2
3
i is :  3
4
i is :  4
hello
nope hello is a string
```

1) My question is why doesnt i get incremented? 
2) why doesnt i=2 i in the second print statement?
3) Does "i" get incremented at all?

Comment: `i` gets assigned to the elements in `a` in the `for i in a` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not over writing the variable. What you want is:

> i += 1

What your code do is actually computing `i+1` but it does not update the variable.

But the idea of a for loop is not to have to increment the variable yourself. It is incremented the next iteration. It you want a more complicated iteration pattern it is preferable that you create it before.

Comment: Hello All,
Not sure If I am doing this right or wrong but I am getting different output based on which version of python I am using. (the above output was taken in pythonv3). Can someone please explain this?

Here is the same output for the above code in "python2"

>>> for i in a:
...     try:
...             print(i)
...             i+1
...             print (("i is : %d") %(i))
...     except:
...             print ("nope " + i + " is a string")
1
2
i is : 1
2
3
i is : 2
3
4
i is : 3
4
5
i is : 4
hello
nope hello is a string

Comment: @MichaelHilburt I get the same output using both python 3.6 and 2.7.13. For the first print, `1`  is the result of your print. But `2` is the result of your computation which is printed as you run this interactively. So you see that the computation is effectively happening.

Comment: Hi @y0da,
I am sorry but I didnt understand by what you meant by "But 2 is the result of your computation which is printed as you run this ***interactively***. So you see that the computation is effectively happening." I

Comment: @MichaelHilburt I mean that if you run these lines in an interpreter, it will output the result of i + 1 even if you do not assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Ahh yes! thats exactly what I did!. Thanks for the explanation sir! much respect!